# Find angle $x$ in the figure below

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

For reference: If $AB = BC$ and $AC = BD$ find x(Answer:$30^o$)

[image]

I found the possible Angles, I drew some auxiliary lines ($DG \parallel AC, NH \perp AC$) but I still couldn't find the relationship for the solution

$\alpha+x+84-\beta +\theta = 180 \implies x = 96-\alpha+\beta-\theta\\
\beta +24-\alpha = 180-138 \implies \beta-\alpha = 18\\
x =114 - \theta $

[image]

Comment: What knowledge does this problem assume? What textbook? If the answer is 40 degrees, I don't see how one could get this from finding congruent triangles

Comment: *just from finding congruent triangles

Comment: I drew this diagram in Geogebra. Apparently, x=30

Comment: @Bometh You have a reason ..I typed it wrong. I've already corrected

Comment: @Mike  Sorry.I typed it wrong. I've already corrected. $\angle x = 30^o$

Comment: @petaarantes thanks that is good to know, but that is not quite what I was asking. For example, writing as $a=|AC|$ and $b=|BC|$, all angles in triangle $ABC$ are known, so using the law of sines[?] we can calculate $b$ in terms of $a$. Then you can use law of cosines to find $d=|AD|$ [namely working in Triangle $ADB$, law of cosines gives $a^2=b^2+d^2-2bd \cos(18)$; $b$ is now known in terms of $a$ so solve for $d$. And then once you have $d$, you have $a$ and angle $DAC$, so law of cosines you can solve for $x$.

Comment: So this is my question: Is law of cosines/law of sines in your toolbox so to speak. If this is a textbook exercise, was it covered yet.

Comment: @Mike IIt's an exercise taken from the internet...apparently there is a solution without trigonometry..maybe with auxiliary lines but I can't say.

Comment: where? do you have a source?

Comment: @Mike it's an old question from a brazilian forum but it's unresolved,

Comment: @petaarantes thanks. This is a very interesting question and your diagrams are really helpful. But it is questions such as these that illustrate the importance of also putting in the context in the question--where the question is from, what techniques are allowed to solve it. It is relevant information that this came from a forum and that a solution that does not use trigonometry is rumored to exist, and that is the solution you are interested in.

Comment: @Mike It appears to be a question of Peruvian geometry. Trigonometry can be used in its basic form, but without the advanced formulas of sum of sine cosines, double arc..etc but they rarely use it in their resolutions

Comment: I just added a solution solely based on Euclidean Geometry. It is also pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trigonometric solution: this can be solved using the identity $~2 \sin 48^\circ \sin 12^\circ = \sin 18^\circ$.

Using law of sines,
$~ \displaystyle \frac{AB}{\sin \angle ADB} = \frac{BD}{\sin 18^\circ} $

Now we know that $BD = AC = 2 AB \sin 48^\circ$

So, $2 \sin 48^\circ \sin ADB = \sin 18^\circ \implies \angle ADB = 12^\circ$

From here, you can see that $F$ is on perp bisector of $AC$ such that $BD = FD = AF = FC$ and we obtain $\angle ADC = \angle CDF - \angle ADF = 30^\circ$. Alternatively, we can also use law of sines in $\triangle BCD$.

---

Geometric solution:

[image]

We first draw an equilateral triangle $\triangle AFC$. Then I take a point $D'$ on the shown line, such that $AF = FD'$. Now we extend $AF$ to $E$ such that $AE = AD'$. Then $D'E = FD' = AF = AC$. Now I find a point $B'$ on the perp bisector of $AC$ such that $B'D' = FD'$.

That means $~\angle B'D'F = 24^\circ$ and hence $\angle B'D'E = 60^\circ$ with $B'D' = D'E$. It follows that $~ \triangle B'D'E$ is equilateral and then $AB'$ must be angle bisector of $\angle D'AE$.

*That shows points $B'$ and $D'$ used in our set up are the same points $B$ and $D$ as given in the question.*

Using $FD = FC$ and $\angle CFD = 48^\circ$, we get $\angle ADC = \angle CDF - \angle ADF = 30^\circ$.

Comment: But it's already a great geometric solution. I tried like you through an auxiliary equilateral triangle but then I couldn't complete it..Thank you

Comment: you are welcome!

Comment: How did you arrive at $\angle AFD=108^o$? I know $\angle AFC = 60$ and $\angle CFD = 48^o$? and $AF=FD?$
With these values, the problem already ended because $\triangle CFD$ (isosceles) $\therefore < FVD = 66^o \implies \triangle ADC, x = 180 - 60-24-66=30^o$

Comment: Yes, you can end it that way too. I used $\angle ADC = \angle CDF - \angle ADF$.

Comment: I am first drawing a equilateral triangle $AFC$. Then I am taking a point $D$ such that $AF = FD$. Then $DE = FD = AF$. Now I find point $B$ on the perp bisector of $AC$ such that $BD = FD$. Next I show $\angle BDF = 24^\circ$ and hence $\angle ADB = 12^\circ$. That leads to $\angle BDE = 60^\circ$ with $BD = DE$ so triangle $BDE$ is equilateral. So $AB$ must be angle bisector of $\angle DAE$. In essence, I am going the other way to show that points $B$ and $D$ in our set up are the same points as given in the question.

Comment: Grateful but I'm frozenk...I found it a little confusing for me..I'll read it more calmly..I didn't understand this question of taking a D point that already exists and making the FD segment have the same size as AF and then saying that DF = DE.

Comment: The solution is wonderful, but as it stays, it's maybe misleading *in presentation*. I had problems to get the point... First, it starts with a trigonometric argument. In it we encouter a point $F$ which is not defined closer.  (The line... "*From here, you can see that $F$ is on perp bisector of...*" - what is $F$ so far?) As it stays i thought first the set-up following is there only to construct this $F$ that makes the trigonometry work. In fact, the "*About-the-set-up*"-part is the synthetic construction+proof... (Also, maybe use other letters $D',B'$ for $D,B$ - or  give us a warning...)

Comment: By the way, this is a very nice solution, i see how it was found from the introductory lines. Maybe some of the nine upvoter of the question will find sooner or later time to give a click also here... +1

Comment: @dan_fulea you make some very good points! :) I will read my answer later and make it easier to follow.

Answer (score 4):

I was searching for a geometric solution inside a "very symmetric setting", but soon after posting a solution was accepted, so i gave up mainly for time reasons, i had no "easy" argument on my way at that point. However, after some weeks i came by chance across the older notices, and could complete the proof with an elementary bridge, so i decided to share the ideas.
Problems like the given one can almost always be connected with special configurations of points and lines related to some regular polygon.
To give an example, the well known Langley problem deals with configurations of lines building angles which are multiples of $10^\circ$. The wiki page
on the [Langley's Adventitious Angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langley%27s_Adventitious_Angles) mentions that generalizations of the Langley configuration is related to regular polygons. Citing from the wiki page:

> Classifying the adventitious quadrangles (...) turns out to be equivalent to classifying all triple intersections of diagonals in **regular polygons**.

---

In our case the angles (like $18^\circ$, $24^\circ$, $30^\circ$) appearing
are multiples of $6^\circ$, so one can try to find a solution related to a $30$-gon. Here is such a possible solution in the spirit of finding
geometric properties of the regular $30$-gon equivalent to the "adventitious (quadr)angles" from the stated problem.

---

Let us realize the given triangle $\Delta ABC$ as the triangle
$$\Delta 707'$$
inside the regular $30$-gon $\Pi$ with vertices labelled $0,1,2,3,\dots,29\in\Bbb Z/30$, the figure is below. The labels are integers considered modulo $30$. It is convenient to use a prime instead of a minus
for the reflection w.r.t. the line $0\;15$, so $-X= X'$, making the notation of triangles, angles, etc. less operational. So for instance $7'=-7=30-7=23$ are equivalent labels for the point $C$. Let $*$ be the reflection w.r.t. the side bisector of $BC$.
Reflect $BD$ by $*$ to get the segment $B^*D^*=CD^*$ of length $BD=AC=77'$.

Then the triangle $\Delta ACD^*=\Delta 77'D^*$ is isosceles in $C=7'$, and since $D\in 73'$, we have $D^*\in (73')^*=7^*{3'}^*=14'4'$.
The needed angle $\widehat{ADC}$ is reflected in
$\widehat{14'D^*0}$, so it is an equivalent task to compute this angle. There is an advantage of involving $D^*$ instead of $D$, because we have already an isosceles triangle $\Delta CD^*A$ to work with, and because of the following claim of concurrence of lines related to the $30$-gon. (The point $D^*$ is the point $X$ in the Claim below.)

[image: math stackexchange 4478459 regular 30-gon]

(The figure is heavily decorated, as it often happens when searching for a solution, please extract only the used ingredients from it, or use the other visible coincidences to find an other solution.)

---

It is enough to show the concurrence of the lines $07=BA$,
and $4'14'$, and $7'9'=C9'$ in order to solve the given problem, because knowing this we have:
$$
\widehat{ADC} =
\widehat{AD^*C} =
\text{Angle between $07$ and $4'14'$}
\\
=\frac12
\left(
\overset\frown{14'7} -
\overset\frown{4'0} 
\right) 
=(9-4)\cdot 6^\circ
=30^\circ\ .
$$
But let us show more:

> **Claim:** In the given $30$-gon $\Pi$ consider the perpendicular bisector of the diameter $5\;10'$ as an axis of symmetry for a reflection $r$. Then the following
> pairs of $r$-reflected lines are concurrent in a point $X$
> of this axis:
> $$
> \begin{aligned}
> 24 &\text{ and } 7'9'   \ , \\
> 07 &\text{ and } 5'12'  \ , \\
> 1'9 &\text{ and }4'14'  \ .
> \end{aligned}
> $$

---

I need a Lemma first:

> **Lemma:** In the given $30$-gon $\Pi$ the diameter $78'$, and the pair of reflected lines w.r.t. to this diameter
>
> - $7'13$ and $9'1$,
> - $4'11$ and $5'12$
>
> are passing through a point $H$.

[image: proof of some adventitious angles property 30-gon regular polygon ONE]

**Proof of the Lemma:**
Define $H\in 78'$ as the intersection $H=9'1\cap 7'13$. Then
$$
\Delta 13H9'\sim \Delta 75'7'
\ ,
\\
\qquad\text{ since }\hat{13}=12^\circ=\hat 7\text{ and }
\hat 9'=(13-1)\cdot 6^\circ=(7-(-5))\cdot 6^\circ = \hat 7'\ .
$$
The position of $H$ on $7'13$ can be computed as:
$$
\frac{H7'}{H13} =
\frac{H9'}{H13} =
\frac{5'7'}{5'7} =
\frac{5'7'}{5'13} 
\ .
$$
Then in $\Delta 5'7'13$ the line $5'H$ is an angle bisector,
showing that $5',H,12'$ are colinear.

$\square$

---

**Proof of the Claim:**
Consider the triangle $\Delta 799'$, and some of its internal an external angle bisectors.

[image: proof of some adventitious angles property 30-gon regular polygon TWO]

- The internal angle bisector in $9$ goes through $1'$, because of
  $
  \overset\frown{71'}=
  \overset\frown{1'9'}
  $ same measure for the arcs, eight "units". Where each "unit"
  is the arc measure $360^\circ/30$, it corresponds to the arc bounded by each edge of the regular $30$-gon.
- The internal bisector in $7$ goes through $15$, since
  $
  \overset\frown{9\;15}=
  \overset\frown{15\;9'}
  $, six "units" each. So the external bisector passes through the opposite of $15$, which is $0$.
- The internal bisector in $9'$ goes through $8$, the mid point of the small arc $\overset\frown{79}$. So the external bisector passes through the opposite of $8$, which is $8-15=-7=7'$.

From here, the $9$-excenter of $\Delta 799'$ is the intersection of the internal, and respectively external angle bisectors
$1'9$, and respectively $07$, $7'9'$. Let us denote this point by $X$.

(The other three, $r$-reflected lines from the claim
are also concurrent in the point $X^r$. Let us show $X=X^r$.)

Let us consider the heights in the triangle $\Delta X79'$:

[image: proof of some adventitious angles property 30-gon regular polygon THREE]

The height from $7$ is $78'$ since $78'\perp 7'9'$ and $X$ is on this last line.
The height from $9'$ is $9'1$ since $9'1\perp 07$ and $X$ is on this last line.
From the Lemma, these two heights intersect in a point $H$ which is also on
$5'12'$, and we note that $5'12'$ is perpendicular on the side
$79'$ of $\Delta X79'$. So the height from $X$ is this line $5'12'$.

This shows $X\in 5'12'$. But $X$ is already also on $r$-reflection of $5'12'$, which is $1'9$. S $X=X^r$.
This completes the proof of the Claim.

$\square$

Comment: @MathLover Oh, yes... but as it stays, your geometric construction is not at the first place, the solution is introduced by the words "*About the set-up*", not really suggestion the start of a proof. But OK, after finding the start of the solution, i removed the "trigonometric" from this answer. I'll maybe comment better on your answer why it was so hard to find the solution in the answer...

Comment: Have a look at my approach! I think you might like it.

Answer (score 2):

A little bit of "reverse engineering" on the problem is quite useful in this case.

We will start with a regular pentagon $DXYZB$, an equilatelar triangle $XYC$ and another equilateral triangle $DYA$.

Our aim becomes now to show that the quadrilateral $ABDC$ satisfies all the original requirements, namely

> 1. $BA \cong BC$,
> 2. $\measuredangle BAC = 42^\circ$,
> 3. $BD \cong AC$,
> 4. $\measuredangle DAC = 24^\circ$.

[image]

Requirement 1. is a straightforward consequence of $BCY \cong ABD$, by SAS criterion.

Since $BC$ bisects $\angle DBZ$, Requirement 2. will be proved once we show that
\begin{equation}\measuredangle ABZ = 42^\circ\tag{1}\label{1}.\end{equation} Given a regular pentagon $PQRST$ and the equilater triangle $PRU$ (see Figure below), we can show that the resulting triangle $STU$ is isosceles with $\measuredangle STU = 42^\circ$. The fact that the triangle is isosceles is a consequence of $U$ lying on the perpendicular bisector of $PR$ and therefore of $ST$. Observe then that $RTU$ is isosceles with $\measuredangle TRU = 24^\circ$. Hence $\measuredangle RTU = 78^\circ$, and from this we get to \eqref{1}.

[image]

Back to the first figure of the post. An easy angle chasing plus ASA criterion yields $ACZ \cong BCD$ which immediately leads us to Requirement 3.

Finally $\measuredangle ADC = 30^\circ$ (which is, by the way, our actual thesis!) and $\measuredangle ACD = 126^\circ$ (angle chasing) yields Requirement 4.
$\blacksquare$

Comment: [+1] How did you come up with this very astute construction ?

Comment: @JeanMarie After some practice I noticed that the presence of some angles (such as $42^\circ$, $48^\circ$, $66^\circ$ may involve constructions based on regular pentagon and triangle. Comparing with the other answer, I assume that there must be a sort of trade-off between number of sides of a single polygon vs. number of polygons you use together in the construction.

Answer (score 0):

@MathLover has given a solution involving relationship :

$$2 \sin 48° \sin 12° = \sin 18°$$

Here is an analytical geometry solution using an analogous relationship, with angle $42°=24°+18°$.

$$2 \ \underbrace{\tan 24°}_{t_1}\underbrace{\tan 42°}_{t_2} = 1-\underbrace{(\tan 24°)^2}_{(t_1)^2}\tag{1}$$

(that can be established by taking the cotangent of $2 \times 24°+42°=90°$).

Let us call $H$ the midpoint of $AC$ which will be taken as the origin, with the line directed by $HC$ (resp. $HB$)  as the horizontal (resp. vertical) axis ; we will take WLOG $C(1,0)$.

As it has been guessed that $\angle ADC$, subtending chord $AC$, should be equal to $30°$, it is rather natural to introduce the circle subtending the same chord with central angle $60° = 2 \times 30°$, i.e., with center $F$ making triangle $FAC$ an equilateral triangle, therefore with radius $2$. Evidently, the coordinates of $F$ are $(0,\sqrt{3})$.

It suffices to show that $D$ belongs to this circle.

By its definition, $D$ is at the intersection of a line and a circle with resp. equations :

$$\begin{cases}y&=&t_1(x+1)\\
x^2+(y-t_2)^2&=&2^2\end{cases}\tag{2}$$

Solving system (2) by eliminating either $x$ or $y$ and taking into account relationship (1), one gets the ordinate of $D$ :

$$y_D=\tfrac12(t_2+\sqrt{3}).$$

i.e., the arithmetical mean of the ordinates of $B$ and $F$. Therefore, the altitude dropped from $D$ onto side $BF$ is its midpoint. As a consequence, triangle $CDB$ is isosceles and its sides issued from $D$ have the same length : $DF=DB=2$, proving that $D$ belongs to the circle mentionned above.

Remark : we need at a certain step of the computation the minimal polynomial of $t_1$, otherwise said the fact that :

$$t_1^6+4\sqrt{3}t_1^5-29t_1^4-24 \sqrt{3}t_1^3+3t_1^2+4\sqrt{3}t_1+1=0$$

but we don't need (happily) its explicit exact value :

$$t_1=\tan (2 \pi/15)=\sqrt{23+10 \sqrt{5}-2 \sqrt{255+114 \sqrt{3}}}$$

Answer (score -2):

Equation AB = BC implies that triangle ABC is isosceles 
Moreover we have given measure of one angle so we can calculate measure of other angles 
and make measure of angle BCD dependent on x

Equation AB = BC implies that triangle ABC is isosceles then base angles have equal measure
From sum of angles measures in ABC we get that measures of angles are equal 42 , 42, 96 in degrees 
From sum of angles measures in ACD we get 
$$
24+42+y+x = 180\\
66+x+y = 180\\
x+y=114\\
y=114-x\\
$$
Now we want to make dependent lengths of the sides in triangle BCD on one side length only
We use law of sines twice to do this

From law of sines in triangle ABC 
$$
\frac{AC}{\sin(96)}=\frac{BC}{\sin(42)}\\
\frac{AC}{\sin(84)}=\frac{BC}{\sin(42)}\\
\frac{AC}{2\sin(42)\cos(42)}=\frac{BC}{\sin(42)}\\
BC = \frac{AC}{2\cos(42)}\\
BC = \frac{BD}{2\cos(42)}\\
$$

From law of sines in triangle ACD 
$$
\frac{AC}{\sin(x)} = \frac{CD}{\sin(24)}\\
CD = \frac{\sin(24)}{\sin(x)}AC\\
CD = \frac{\sin(24)}{\sin(x)}BD\\
$$

From law of cosines in triangle BDC

$$
BD^2=\frac{BD^2}{4\cos^2(42)}+\frac{\sin^2(24)}{\sin^2(x)}-2\frac{\sin(24)}{\sin(x)}BD\frac{BD}{2\cos(42)}\cos(114-x)\\
BD^2=BD^2\left(\frac{1}{4\cos^2(42)}+\frac{\sin^2(24)}{\sin^2(x)}-\frac{\sin(24)}{\sin(x)\cos(42)}\cos(114-x)\right)\\
1 = \frac{1}{4\cos^2(42)}+\frac{\sin^2(24)}{\sin^2(x)}-\frac{\sin(24)}{\sin(x)\cos(42)}\cos(114-x)\\
$$
This equation can be expressed as quadratic in terms of $\cot(x)$

$$
1 = \frac{1}{4\cos^2(42)}+\frac{\sin^2(24)}{\sin^2(x)}-\frac{\sin(24)}{\sin(x)\cos(42)}\cos(114-x)\\
1 = \frac{1}{4\cos^2(42)}+\sin^2(24)\frac{\cos^2(x)+\sin^2(x)}{\sin^2(x)}+\frac{\sin(24)}{\cos(42)}\frac{\cos(66)\cos(x)-\sin(66)\sin(x)}{\sin(x)}\\
1 = \frac{1}{4\cos^2(42)}+\sin^2(24)\frac{\cos^2(x)+\sin^2(x)}{\sin^2(x)}+\frac{\sin(24)}{\cos(42)}\frac{\sin(24)\cos(x)-\cos(24)\sin(x)}{\sin(x)}\\
1 = \frac{1}{4\cos^2(42)}+\sin^2(24)\left(\cot^2(x)+1\right)+\frac{\sin^2(24)}{\cos(42)}\cot(x)-\frac{\sin(24)\cos(24)}{\cos(42)}\\
1 = \frac{1}{4\cos^2(42)}+\sin^2(24)\left(\cot^2(x)+1\right)+\frac{\sin^2(24)}{\cos(42)}\cot(x)-\frac{2\sin(24)\cos(24)}{2\cos(42)}\\
\frac{1}{4\cos^2(42)}+\sin^2(24)\cot^2(x) + \sin^2(24) - 1 + \frac{\sin^2(24)}{\cos(42)}\cot(x)-\frac{\sin(48)}{2\cos(42)}=0\\
\sin^2(24)\cot^2(x)+\frac{\sin^2(24)}{\cos(42)}\cot(x)+\frac{1}{4\cos^2(42)}-\cos^2(24)-\frac{1\cos(42)}{2\cos(42)}=0\\
\sin^2(24)\cot^2(x)+\frac{\sin^2(24)}{\cos(42)}\cot(x)+\frac{1-4\cos^2(42)\cos^2(24)-2\cos^2(42)}{4\cos^2(42)} = 0\\
\cot^2(x)+\frac{1}{\cos(42)}\cot(x)+\frac{1-4\cos^2(42)\cos^2(24)-2\cos^2(42)}{4\cos^2(42)\sin^2(24)}=0\\
\left(\cot(x)+\frac{1}{2\cos(42)}\right)^2-\frac{1}{4\cos^2(42)}+\frac{1-4\cos^2(42)\cos^2(24)-2\cos^2(42)}{4\cos^2(42)\sin^2(24)}=0\\
\left(\cot(x)+\frac{1}{2\cos(42)}\right)^2-\frac{1}{4\cos^2(42)}-\frac{4\cos^2(42)\cos^2(24)+2\cos^2(42)-1}{4\cos^2(42)\sin^2(24)}=0\\
\left(\cot(x)+\frac{1}{2\cos(42)}\right)^2-\frac{4\cos^2(42)\cos^2(24)+2\cos^2(42)-1+\sin^2(24)}{4\cos^2(42)\sin^2(24)}=0\\
\left(\cot(x)+\frac{1}{2\cos(42)}\right)^2-\frac{4\cos^2(42)\cos^2(24)+2\cos^2(42)-\cos^2(24)}{4\cos^2(42)\sin^2(24)}=0\\
$$

$$
\cot(x)=\frac{-\sin(24)\mp\sqrt{4\cos^2(42)\cos^2(24)+2\cos^2(42)-\cos^2(24)}}{2\cos(42)\sin(24)}\\
$$ 
but only root with + sign works 
It should be simplified further but value of RHS is $\cot(162)$ and $\cot(30)$